# controlling where registered users land on login in Joomla

Tags: joomla, registration

I am not quite a novice yet in Joomla but I am working my way up to that level of expertise!

I have never used Joomla and I have a friend who's asked if I can help with their website.

Basically, they have a members area which registered users can access however, when a registered user logs in, they see the default home page for the website instead of the members home page which they have created specifically for the members.

What is the simplest way to redirect users on login to go to the members home page instead of the default public home page?

They currently have a menu item which is called "Member Login" which is of type "User >> Login" which has an Access level of "Public" - I have set the variable "Login Redirection URL" as follows:

[image]

I have also tried configuring the module mod_login by setting the Login Redirection Page as follows:

[image]

But neither of these have changed the login behaviour.

The Article I am redirecting to is "Members Home Page"  - This page has an Access level of "Registered"

Any help would be wonderful?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Joomla 2.5, then there are parameters you can set in the menu item to determine where a user is redirected to on login and logout. You just put the appropriate URL in the field and your done.

From what you are describing, the site is most likely J1.5. The User > Login menu also has the same redirect parameters, so you can still fill those in. However, I would HIGHLY recommend upgrading the site to at least J2.5 before the site gets hacked.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will consider the upgrade, or at least recommend it to my friend.  As for the login parameters - I found parameters on both: the menu item (Login Redirection URL) and the module (mod_login: Login Redirection Page) and I set both of those but it still doesn't redirect

Comment: That is a bit of a problem. Any extension that interacts with the login process can break the redirect. May extensions like Virtuemart, JomSocial, Community Builder, and all kinds of plugins take over the login process from Joomla core. You'll need to determine if there are any extensions that are conflicting with the login redirect before we can give you any more advice.